# ASP.NET MVC - Cascading Dropdownlist for Date (Month/Day only)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My Requirement is to create two dropdown lists for Month and Day

When the user pick Month it will populate the Day dropdown with correct number of days

I'm starting along with this code

```
@Html.DropDownList("month", Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)}), "-- Month --")
@Html.DropDownList("day", Enumerable.Range(1, 31).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()}), "-- Day --")
```

For February - ill just display the maximum day for it (29)

And no - datepicker is not a requirement. It would also be awesome if I dont need to use Javascript.

Comment: It's impossible without Javascript, unless you use ASP.NET Web Form.

Comment: The only way to achieve this without javascript/jquery would be to select the month, post the form, populate the day list based on the selected month and return the view. Use javascript/jquery (it can all be done in the client and it will give far better performance)